# Extend /dev/sdb1 without unmounting?

Tags: server, disk

There seems to be about a million web pages about extending the system partition of your Ubuntu installation, and how you need to do a lot of steps to extend your disk. But nothing about increasing the size of a secondary volume.

I have a production web server running Ubuntu 14.04.
I've added an extra disk, 40GB in size, and moved, mounted and fstab'ed /var to it.

It all works as intended.
However, now I've added 60gb more disk to it in VMWare, and I can't do umount on the disk, since it's busy.

Is it really no way to increase the disk size without interupting the web server?
Even Windows Server 2003 can achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only extend / resize the physical partition if the file system is unmounted.

The only exception is if you use LVM. If you use LVM you would first add or extend the physical volume, then extend the logical volume, then extend the file system.

With LVM, adding a new physical partition, sdb1 in this example.

First make a partition on /dev/sdb, either with fdisk, parted, or gparted

Then make a file system:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Add the partition to the (LVM) physical volume,  VolGroup00 in this example

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/sdb1
```

Extend the logical volume , LogVol00 in this example

```
lvextend -L +10G /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

Resize the filesystem . I know this works for ext3 and ext4. It will not work with ext2. I am not sure about other file systems

```
resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

Adjust your /dev/sdb1 volume groups, and partition to your server.

If you are NOT using LVM, you are out of luck and will have to manage your partitions with a live .iso

Comment: Alright thanks for the reply. I get it. :-/

I partitioned everything using LVM at first installation, but I neved added the sdb1 one to the LVM, so my bad.

I can do umount /var in single user mode. How would I go about extending it while it's unmounted?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching on how to this with a CloudAtCost provider the below is what worked for me:

```
pvscan && vgextend localhost-vg /dev/sda3 && lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/localhost-vg/root && resize2fs /dev/localhost-vg/root
```